# How to use NSE in dplyr to refer to one variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to write a function for use in a `dplyr` chain to arrange grouped data by a given variable and then to check that that variable is strictly increasing integers (eg, 1,2,3,...). To clarify, I mean every integer in order, not just increasing integers. So 1,2,4,... should fail.

The idea would be to have something like this in the end, that would look like this, and provide an error if x was not 1,2,3,... for every group.

```
d %>% group_by(group) %>% check(x)
```

I've written a SE version of this that seems to work, as follows, but am stuck on the NSE version.

```
check_ <- function(.data, var) {
  checkint <- function(x) { stopifnot(x == seq_along(x)) }
  do(.data, {
    . <- dplyr::arrange_(., var)
    checkint(lazyeval::lazy_eval(var, data=.))
    .
  })
}
```

In the documentation, it looks like I should be using `lazy` to process a single variable, but this doesn't work right when the variable I'm passing in also exists in the global environment.

```
checkX <- function(.data, var) {
  check_(.data, lazyeval::lazy(var))
}

d <- expand.grid(group=1:2, x=3:1)
x <- 5 ## put an "x" in the global environment
d %>% group_by(group) %>% checkX(x)

## Error: incorrect size (1), expecting : 3
```

I do have a version of the NSE that seems to work, but calling `lazy_dots` feels wrong because I only ever want one variable.

```
check <- function(.data, ...) {
  check_(.data, lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)[[1]])
}
```

Comment: I want it to fail if it's c(1,2,4), I'll clarify in the question. It also felt cleaner to me to not have the byproduct of the summary, as what I really want to do is to pipe the output of this to another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `lazyeval` has been changing.  The [latest vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) doesn't even reference the `lazy()` function. It does seem to have problems with variables in scope (more on that at the bottom). There are now we functions being encouraged though they still haven't made their way into all of the "tidyverse" yet.

It looks like the function you want is `expr_find`. If we define `checkX` as

```
checkX <- function(.data, var) {
  check_(.data, lazyeval::expr_find(var))
}
```

Then this will work

```
x <- 5
d %>% group_by(group) %>% checkX(x)
```

(or at least it does with `lazyeval_0.2.0` and `dplyr_0.5.0`)

But going back to the first example from the [old vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval-old.html)

```
library(lazyeval)
# `x` does not exist here
f <- function(x = a - b) {
  lazy(x)
}
f()
# <lazy>
#   expr: a - b
#   env:  <environment: 0x000000000663d618>
exists("x")
# [1] FALSE
f(x)
# <lazy>
#   expr: x
#   env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
x <- 101
f(x)
# <lazy>
#   expr: 101
#   env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Or another even more simple example

```
# rm(x)
lazy(x)
# <lazy>
#   expr: x
#   env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
x <- 100
lazy(x)
#  <lazy>
#   expr: 100
#   env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Somewhere its evaluating the parameter x so it's never being preserved in the lazy object if it exists in the environment it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for investigating! Maybe I'll wait to do more complex things with dplyr until things have settled down. I also see that Hadley now is souring somewhat on NSE, so maybe I'll just stick to the SE methods.